# D3.js tool tips on hover

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I,m following this tutorial for tool tips for my graph :

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c37cb8e630aaef7df30d

and its working like a charm !

However there is one issue...

The current graph showing in the tutorial has black dots on the line...

I want the tool tips and black dots to appear only when i hover on them and not always like it is currently showing.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: How will the user know where to hover when all the dots go away?

Comment: when ever the user hovers on the graph and a dot appears...he/she will have an idea that some hover functionality is implemented on the graph and he/she can view the data and the dates on hover.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer with mouseout:
https://plnkr.co/edit/9Ej1MYpGqxBdeWO2FUNO?p=preview

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
// show circle selected
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
          .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 0.9);

.on('mouseout', function(d) {
    // hide the circle
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    // hide the tooltip
    d3.selectAll(".tooltip")
      .transition()
      .duration(100)
      .style("opacity",0);
```

To use `mouseout`, you need to move the tooltip slightly up, and move the whole `svg` a bit downwards.

```
div.html(
    '<a href= "http://google.com">' + // The first <a> tag
    formatTime(d.date) +
    "</a>" +                          // closing </a> tag
    "<br/>"  + d.close)  
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")          
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 42) + "px"); // up a bit
var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50}, // down a bit
```

Since `mouseout` is very sensitive, the circle will disappear immediately after you move away your mouse, so it is better to increase the radius a bit:

```
 svg.selectAll("dot")                                   
    .data(data)                                         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 8)   // slightly bigger for human reaction
```

Still, I think without `mouseout` is a better and more intuitive approach:

Old working example (takes a few seconds to load): https://plnkr.co/edit/IitMgKW0jDYlWifokcZB?p=preview

The changes you need to make is in `.on("mouseover", function(d)`, add the following code:

```
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // hide other circles
      d3.selectAll('circle')
        .style("opacity", 0);
    // show circle selected
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0.9);
```

`.on("mouseout", function(d)` would not work for this case because the circles overlap with the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks...but the "mouseout" functionality is not working...i,ve tried to add the "mouseout" code but nothing seems to work....is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: @SteveJax your tooltip is blocking the circle so the mouseout event is not triggered. If you move your tooltip slightly away it should work. I will update my answer with mouseout later.

Comment: @SteveJax updated, but `mouseout` seems to be too sensitive for fast mouse movements. I would suggest stick with the old approach.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly now....a little more fix to the code here because the tool tips were not hiding perfectly. 
 
You also need to add this  :  d3.selectAll(".tooltip")
      .transition()
    .duration(100)
      .style("opacity",0);
(Please update the code in plunker....i,m giving +1 to your answer).
Thanks.

Comment: By the way...i would really like to ask you something here...setting the opacity to "0" did not helped at all...but adding .transition() and .duration(100) fixed the issue perfectly....how did you came up with this transition and duration technique and whats it doing here ? How is this helping ?

Comment: @SteveJax updated. For me with or without `.transition() and .duration(100)` yields the same effect. Maybe there is some other code manipulating the tooltip concurrently, hence the direct change in property `opacity` is overridden. Using `transition` delays the manipulation, preventing potential conflicts.

Comment: @SteveJax `.transition() and .duration(100)` means instead of changing opacity from a to b **instantly**, the change will take place over **100 milliseconds gradually** (using javascript).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple d3 tooltip you can look the code! (It's very little )

https://github.com/cbertelegni/tooltip_d3js/

```
function tooltipd3(tltp_name){

"use strict";

var s = {};
s.name = tltp_name ? tltp_name : "tooltipd3";
s.w = 0;    // width tooltip
s.h = 0;    // height tooltip

s.t = d3.select("body").append("div") // tooltip html node
    .attr("class", s.name)
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .style("position", "absolute");

s.mouseover = function(html) {
    /** @param {string} html - Is the content for tooltip */
    s.t.html(html)
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);

    /** After innerhtml on tooltip get w & h */
    s.get_t_size();
};

s.mousemove = function(){
    s.t.style("left", (d3.event.pageX - s.w/2) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - s.h - 5) + "px")
        .style("opacity", 1);
};

s.mouseout = function() {
    s.t.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1e-6)
        .each("end", function(){
            s.t.html("");
        });
};

/** Get width and height of tooltip and set w & h of Tooltip class */
s.get_t_size = function(){
    var size = s.t.node().getBoundingClientRect();
    s.w = size.width;
    s.h= size.height;
};

return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eric said in the comments, this approach is not exactly user-friendly. But, if you want it, here it is:

First, set the opacity of the circles to 0:

```
.attr("opacity", 0)
```

Then, on mousemove:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1);
  div.transition()//the rest of the code
```

Don't forget to create a mouse out to make them transparent again:

```
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks...but according to @paradite the "mouseout" functionality would not work for this case because the circles overlap with the tooltip...i,ve tried adding the "mouseout" code but nothing seems to work....is there a way to fix this ?